# Filter nested documents in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am having some trouble when trying to filter nested documents in Meteor, and I don't want to use MongoDB Aggregation to unwind my documents.

An example of my Users document

```
{
   Publications:[{ 
       type:1
   },{ 
       type:2
   }]
}
```

When I do a find to get only type 1, I get the expected result - they return only the User documents who have a type 1 publication, but they also return the publications with type 2 too, because they are in the publications array of that User.

I can make a loop in the results to remove these publications manually before publishing, but I don't think this is the right approach.

Can someone please help guide me to a better solution?

```
Edited
```

The Sean answer is good but not the right yet, the projection dont work on meteor. That work on robomongo, but in the project still returning the 2 publications types of the user.

Comment: You can retrieve subsets of documents from mongodb using [projections](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations-introduction/#projections).

Comment: @ChristianFritz the projection do that, Sean give a example above.

Comment: @LuanSoares: thanks, I didn't know about the `$` operator in projections. I removed the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this query a shot.

```
Meteor.users.find(
    { 'Publications.type': 1 },
    { fields: { 'Publications.$': 1 } }
);
```

This should find users with publications of type 1 and will only include those matching publications in the output. You can include other fields in the output as well by including them in the [projection parameter](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations-introduction/#projections) (e.g., `{ 'Publications.$': 1, profile: 1 }`).

One thing to be aware of though. I think queries that use the `{ 'Publications.$': 1 }` projection can only be done on the server side. The minimongo implementation used on the client does not support it.

More info about the `$` projection can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_).

Comment: Just a correction

    find({'Publications.tipo':'1'},{fields:{'Publications.$':1}});

Comment: Ah right. I was using the pure MongoDB syntax. Will update my answer to reflect the Meteor syntax.